# FontFamily does not exist

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

Want to set global `FontFamily` and `FontSize` in a `ResourceDictionary`, but it's not an option.  Why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That works for me:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App59">
    <FontFamily
        x:Key="MyFamily">Consolas</FontFamily>
    <x:Double
        x:Key="MyFontSize">48</x:Double>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Page

```
<Page
    x:Class="App59.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App59"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary
                    Source="SomeResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBlock
            Text="Hello"
            FontSize="{StaticResource MyFontSize}"
            FontFamily="{StaticResource MyFamily}"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Funny answer - now try to answer my question :).

Comment: Let me expand and if that doesn't work for you - clarify your question.

Comment: I was looking for the intellisense to offer a FontFamily option, didn't realize I had to do it this way.  Also, an error I get with double is that Double is not supported in a Win App project.

Comment: I don't know about that one. It worked for me in a Win 8.1 XAML project in VS2013 Update 2 RC (with ReSharper).